# How to setup Windows Remote Desktop Connection Broker HA with SQL Server Express?

Tags: windows, sql-server, remote-desktop, rds, windows-server-2022

I am preparing an environment in which Remote Desktop Connection Broker for which HA is to be based on SQL server (windows server standard 2022)

In my case, the SQL server is MS SQL Server Express 2022 - I have properly prepared DNS, group in AD, permissions granted for this group, firewalls turned off, appropriate ODBC connector.

But every time I get a connection error - the database is created from SSMS (empty).

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDFSs.png)
[connectionstring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD0DS.png)

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:SERVERNAME\NAMEDINSTANCE,1433;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Remote Desktop Services Connection Broker;Database=rds_db
```

I used these two paths in the configuration: https://rdr-it.com/en/rds-farm-high-availability-service-broker-configuration/ https://woshub.com/configure-rds-connection-broker-high-availability-windows-server/

Isn't SQL Express sometimes the problem? I have port 1433 and the wizard clearly says port 1434

What else can I pay attention to?

How to resolve this problem?

---

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDFSs.png)

PLS help, Imm trying same thing in lab - but same error.

[lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD0DS.png)

quick summary:

sql.lab.net - sql server express with new empty db: rds_db

rds1.lab.net - first rds host with broker role

rds2.lab.net - second rds host

in active directory im have secuirty group with this two hosts

[ad_group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0D22.png)

in sql im have login maped to this security group (dbowner, dbcreator, public, sysadmin)

[sql_login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rpDq.png)

all firewalls are down - check telnet from rds1.lab.net to sql.lab.net  port 1433 is open

on rds1.lab.net and rds2.lab.net in local group: RDS Managment Server i'm add hosts rds1,rds2 and network service

[local group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x628r.png)

in DNS im have two records A in revers lab.net zone with name rds.lab.net (ip of rds1) and rds.lab.net (ip of rds2) - round robin

[dns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfnD7.png)

Comment: If you haven't confirmed what port your database/server is listening on, do it using netstat. Typically default instances are on 1433, and named instances on another high port. 1434 is typically for the SQL Browser, which you don't need if you know the port that you have configured for your rds_db database

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you need to check:

Make sure your Instance is really listening on TCP 1433, if you want to connect this way.
Open `Sql Server Configuration Manager`. Expand on `SQL Server Network Configuration` and select `Protocols for YOURINSTANCE`. Right klick on `TCP/IP` and change to `IP Addresses`. Either your IPv4 Address or `IPALL` needs to have the TCP Port set to 1433.
Verify this by looking for the sqlserver process in `Resource Monitor` in the `Network` Tab at `Listening Ports`.
Also maybe try to connect from another host with SSMS.

Is that ODBC Driver you want to use installed? Check in the `ODBC Data Source Administator` in the `Drivers` tab.
Is it even supported by the application you want to configure? For testing purpose try using the `Native Client`.

Maybe check this Documentation too: [Add the RD Connection Broker server to the deployment and configure high availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-connection-broker-cluster)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this request for help is nine months old at the time of my reply, but I struggled with this same issue and maybe what worked for me will help someone else.

A [post on Microsoft's SQL Server Blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228) explains:

> Similar to the HTTP to HTTPS default changes made in web browsers a
> few years back (and the security reasons for them), we are changing
> the default value of the `Encrypt` connection option from `no` to
> `yes`/`mandatory`. (New encrypt values "mandatory" and "optional",
> synonymous with "yes" and "no", respectively, have been added to
> better describe encryption behavior.)...
>
> The action item if you are affected by the Encrypt change is to either
> (in order of recommendation):
>
> - Install a trusted certificate on your server.
> - Change your client's Encrypt connection string setting (or connection property) to optional/no.

I was able to connect to the database after adding "Encrypt=Optional;" to the end of my connection string.

Modifying the poster's connection string in the same way should work:

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:SERVERNAME\NAMEDINSTANCE,1433;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Remote Desktop Services Connection Broker;Database=rds_db;Encrypt=Optional;
```